# assigning variable new value to change element nodeValue

Tags: javascript, performance

The following code works fine but I want to make it better:

```
function prodNameTrim(selector){
        var el = document.getElementsByClassName(selector);
        var len = el.length;
        for(i = 0; i<len; i++){
            aObj = el[i].getElementsByTagName('a');
            txtNode = aObj[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            if(txtNode.length > 26){
                txtNode = txtNode.substring(0, 27) + ' ...';
            }
            aObj[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = txtNode;
        }
    }
```

What I don't like about it is that I first establish txtNode before the condition like so:

```
txtNode = aObj[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

After I process the variable through my conditional to truncate the string with an ellipses, I do the following to replace the text in the DOM:

```
aObj[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = txtNode;
```

I have to believe there is a better way to do this but I'm not sure what that is, I feel as if I'm breaking the DRY rule.

Comment: Question is better suited at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DavidBarker: Thanks for mentioning that, I didn't know that this existed and will use that instead from now on for these types of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest this:

```
function prodNameTrim(selector){
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName(selector),
        len = el.length, node;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        node = el[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].firstChild;
        if(node.nodeValue.length > 26){
            node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.substring(0, 27) + ' ...';
        }
    }
}
```

Changes:

1. Declare all local variables (so no implicit globals - you weren't declaring `i`, `aObj` or `txtNode`)
2. Skip the `aObj` intermediate as it isn't needed
3. Avoid the textNode intermediate as it isn't need
4. Assign directly to nodeValue
5. Make the assignment to nodeValue only inside the `if` statement since that's the only place it changes
6. Use `.firstChild` instead of `.childNodes[0]`

---

I wonder if this would work (probably requires IE9 or higher and would like to see the HTML to know for sure and run some browser tests), but the general idea is to use `querySelectorAll()` and combine the two searches into one more involved CSS selector:

```
function prodNameTrim(rootClass) {
    var items = document.querySelectorAll("." + rootClass + " a:first-of-type"), node;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        node = items[i].firstChild;
        if (node.nodeValue.length > 26) {
            node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.substring(0, 27) + ' ...';
        }
    }
}
```

Note, this second implementation assumes that the argument to `prodNameTrim()` is a class name (as it was in the OP's version).

---

Or, if there's only one link tag in each selector parent, then you could simply use this which should work in all modern browsers:

```
function prodNameTrim(rootClass) {
    var items = document.querySelectorAll("." + rootClass + " a"), node;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        node = items[i].firstChild;
        if (node.nodeValue.length > 26) {
            node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.substring(0, 27) + ' ...';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I'd thought of that. Oh wait, I did. Though you explained it in a much neater way, so I guess +1 anyway.

Comment: Added another idea using a single selector.

Comment: @jfriend00: thanks very much for the reply, question regarding avoiding globals.  I see var items declared but then node does not use the key word var ... how does that work so that node is NOT a global variable?

Comment: another question I would have is the difference between using firstChild vs childNodes[0].  I understand that both are accessing the same element in the DOM but is there a performance advantage in using one over the other?  Under which circumstances would using childNode[x] be preferable?

Comment: @max7 - `node` is declared in the first or second line of the function (at the end of the line) depending upon which version you're looking at.  I didn't do a performance test on `.childNodes[0]` vs. `.firstChild`, but intuitively it seems like `.firstChild` would be simpler so either faster or at worst the same speed as `.childNodes[0]`.

Comment: @jfriend00: regarding node, I see where it is declared, my question is regarding the fact that the keyword var is not used.  Part of the critique of my original code is that I was creating global variable by not using this keyword (a fair criticism) so considering this, I wondered why in your code var was not used when declaring node i.e. node is a global variable in your example.  Not sure if this was intended if so why.

Comment: @max7 - `var` works for one or more comma separated variables.  So `var x, y, z;` declares all three variables in the current scope.  It is a shortcut for `var x; var y; var z;`.

Comment: @jfriend00: thanks again for your response and please don't think I'm being unnecessarily contentious, I just want to really understand this.  I do understand the concept of declaring multiple variables at once as you demonstrated.  But when I look at your declaration of node, I do not see the keyword var there in either example.  Am I missing something?  Thanks again for sharing your expertise.

Comment: @max7 - It's this form `var items = expression, node;` which is the same as `var items = expression; var node;`.  In addition to declaring multiple variables with one `var` statement, you can also assign an initial value to any of them in the same single `var` statement`.  For example, you can do this `var x = 1, y = 2, x = 3, z;` and that declares four variables in the local scope.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to avoid repeating the `aObj[0].childNodes[0]` part everywhere you can use your `txtNode` variable to refer to the node itself, rather than its value:

```
function prodNameTrim(selector){
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName(selector);
    var len = el.length;
    var txtNode;  // declare txtNode with var
    for(var i = 0; i<len; i++){
        txtNode = el[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].childNodes[0];
        if(txtNode.nodeValue.length > 26){
            txtNode.nodeValue = txtNode.nodeValue.substring(0, 27) + ' ...';
        }
    }
}
```

You'll notice that you still end up repeating `txtNode.nodeValue` everywhere, but it's better than having to include `aObj[0].childNodes[0]` every time. And the line that you had after the `if` statement to write the substring version back to the node is not needed, since that update now takes place directly inside the `if`.

Note also that you should declare all of your variables with `var` or they'll become globals. (And the way I've shown above doesn't actually need the `aObj` variable at all.)

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to do the conditional truncation in one line, you could do something like this:

```
function prodNameTrim(selector){
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName(selector),
        len = el.length, node;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        node = el[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].firstChild;
        node.nodeValue.substring(0, 27) + (node.nodeValue.length > 26 ? ' ...', '')
    }
}
```

Comment: This line won't work `node = el[i].getElementsByTagName('a').childNodes[0];` because `getElementsByTagName()` returns an array-like result.

Comment: @BenjaminWarren: thanks very much for the response.  Question: why use firstChild instead of childNodes[x]?  Is there some advantage?

Comment: @max7: I don't believe there's any advantage other than readability. firstChild is more semantic than childNodes[0]. However, I must admit that I just copied that line from jfriend00's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it the right way – except for the fact that you're introducing an unnecessary global variable. The first assignment should be:

```
var txtNode = aObj[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

Use the `var` statement! You can also declare the variable before the `for` loop, at the top of the function. As noted by nnnnnn, you're also creating unintended globals for `i` and `aObj`. So you could fix all three problems by inserting this right before the `for` loop:

```
var i, aObj, txtNode;
```

Comment: I agree that your opinion is a valid answer, but note that `i` and `aObj` also need to be declared with `var`.

Comment: Removed my comments - have said my piece.